# Is it possible to remove the "week" in html5 input type week?

Tags: html, css, input, webkit

I'm trying to remove the input text "week" in the input type week(Vecka).
Is it possible?

**HTML**

```
<input type="week" />;
```

[image]

Is there some webkit class to use in css?
This is from Google Chrome. Is it diffrent between browsers?

**JSFIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/o9ezrf2m/

Comment: Browser support for week fields is very low. To improve compatibility, you may have to rely on scripts to provide advanced controls and to check values conformance before submission.

Comment: @Boudyhesham I figured. I have a table that are growing all time. In that table i have editable date inputs. I was using flatpickr at first.. but the loadtime get to big. Is there any script that don't take so much loading time?